# How to convert slice object to boolean index?

Tags: python, numpy

### TL;DR:

Knowing the value of `NUM_ROWS`, `rmin` and `rmax`, how do I construct a bool array `my_idx` such that `np.arange(NUM_ROWS)[my_idx] == np.arange(NUM_ROWS)[rmin:rmax]`? Can the construction operation be broadcasted, if `rmin` and `rmax` are arrays ad I'm interested in all slices `[slice(from, to) for from, to in zip(rmin, rmax)]`?

---

### Long version with details

I have an array of polygons in a 2D image and I want to find rows and columns of the image that don't contain a polygon. In order to do this fast, I'm trying to vectorize the code as much as possible.

I calculate the extreme points of each polygon on both dimension and obtain for each polygon the `min_row`, `min_col`, `max_row` and `max_col` values. Let's consider just the rows (as for the columns it 's the same algorithm) and assume that, for example, these are the values I obtain for two polygons:

```
NUM_ROWS = 10
# Two intervals: slice(1,5) and slice(7,8)
row_mins = np.array([1, 7], dtype=np.int32)
row_maxs = np.array([5, 8], dtype=np.int32)
```

I want now to merge the intervals in a way equivalent to:

```
row_mask = np.zeros(NUM_ROWS)
for rmin, rmax in zip(row_mins, row_maxs):
  row_mask[rmin:rmax] = 1
```

however, it should avoid the for loop and repeated setting of values in row_mask.
I thought of doing this by turning each range into a bool array and using `np.logical_or.reduce()`, but I can't find a way to generate the bool array equivalent to the `[rmin:rmax]` index.
Is there a way to convert a slice object to a bool index?

Comment: Are you looking for a mask on 2D arrays or 1D arrays? I have added a method you can use for 1D arrays.

Comment: The masks are 1D (it's one mask for rows and one for columns of a 2D array). You can imagine the masks as the projection of the 2D polygons on the row and column axes.

Comment: Makes sense. then i assume you would just create the 2 masks in the same way with slices and use them to index the 2D image directly?

Comment: No, the masks are later needed to select crop points that don't truncate any of the polygons.

Comment: ah ok, got it. You also mention that you want to generate a boolean mask using `np.logical_or` at the end of your answer, because working with slice() is a bit painful with numpy. I prefer sticking to numpy methods like `np.arange()`, but i could try with slices as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT: Found the right way to do it.**

I stand corrected. There IS a way to unpack a list of slices inside `np.r_` and its as simple as using a `tuple()`. That means, once you have your slices mapped to the rmin and rmax arrays, you can simply convert them into an array with `np.r_` and use that to update the values of the mask to 1.

```
import numpy as np

NUM_ROWS = 15

## 3 slices (1:5), (7:10), (12:14)
row_mins = np.array([1, 7, 12])
row_maxs = np.array([5, 10, 14])

mask = np.zeros(NUM_ROWS) #Zeros
slices = list(map(slice,row_mins,row_maxs)) #List of slices
mask[np.r_[tuple(slices)]]=1     #get ranges from list of slices and then update mask
mask
```

```
array([0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0.])
```

---

**Old method I recommended -**

If you want to make a mask with multiple `slices`, then you can do this **without a for loop** (vectorized), by using `np.hstack` with `np.arange` to get all the indexes and then set them to 1.

```
import numpy as np

NUM_ROWS = 15

## 3 slices (1:5), (7:10), (12:14)
row_mins = np.array([1, 7, 12])
row_maxs = np.array([5, 10, 14])

mask = np.zeros(NUM_ROWS)  #Zeros
idx = np.hstack(list(map(np.arange,row_mins,row_maxs)))  #Indexes to choose
mask[idx]=1  #Set to 1
mask
```

```
array([0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0.])
```

---

EDIT: Another way -

You could use `np.eye()` -

```
s = slice(1,4)

mask = np.eye(10)[s].sum(0)
print(mask)
```

```
[0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

Over a list of slices -

```
masks = [np.eye(NUM_ROWS)[slice(i,j)].sum(0) for i,j in zip(row_mins, row_maxs)]
final = np.logical_or.reduce(masks)
final
```

```
array([False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False,  True,  True,
        True, False, False,  True,  True, False])
```

Comment: Though this technically doesn't answer the question as I wrote it, this is in the end what I actually need for my code, thank you! I was concerned this wouldn't work with overlapping ranges, but I just tested it and it seems to work as intended, no need to pass through the bool indices

Comment: Glad to help, Ill try to add an alternate solution inline with your prefered methods as well.

Comment: Also, this works with overlapping ranges because you are just setting each of the indexes selected to 1 in the view from mask. setting the index 4 to a value of 1 multiple times., will not effect the mask at the end. But if you have a lot of overlapping ranges then you could do a `set(list(map()))` over the list of indexes, to avoid multiple updates to same indexes.

Comment: To clarify, in your question `How to convert slice object to boolean index?` are you ok with a method to convert a single slice to a bool mask or its necessary to have multiple slices?

Comment: I would say that, ideally, the goal is for multiple slices. The single slice is a good start though (and it could be useful for other people landing here searching for the same thing).

Comment: Oh , ok, with a single slice its super easy to use a `np.eye` and reduce it. I am updating my answer for your reference.

Comment: This think is that you cant "unpack" a list of slices inside a numpy advanced indexing. So , I can do `np.r_[1:3, 5:6]` but I cant do, `np.r_[list_of_slices]`. Ill see if there is an alternative but if the `np.r_` could work with a input list fo slices, that would not require anything else :)

Comment: I stand corrected. Please ignore my previous comment. Do check my updated answer.

Comment: This is great! Thanks for updating your solution, I've learned a lot from your examples :)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
arr = np.arange(NUM_ROWS)
bool_indices = (arr >= rmin) & (arr < rmax)
```

As you are looking for the intersection between the two, a logical `and` between them should create that array.

Using the rest of your solution:

```
arrs = [(b >= rmin) & (b<rmax) for rmin,rmax in zip(row_mins,row_maxs)]
mask = np.logical_or.reduce(arrs)
```